# Xcode 6.1.1 Storyboard changes layout when I re-open the project

Tags: ios8, xcode6, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

When I open xcode and create layout everything looks pretty much like it should (meaning that the storyboard view controller looks pretty much like the preview)

But when I close out of xcode and re-open it... the view looks like this. This is concerning not just because its difficult to work on, but also because it seems that the storyboard file knows these aren't where they should be. If I click on any individual element it is looking for me to update the constraints for this new layout which is completely inaccurate.

I've tried moving all the items back to the middle, and re-laying out the whole thing, but this takes about 5+ minutes each time I want to make a change. I'm wondering if there is a way to reset the storyboard back to what it should be, or if there is some setting that I have wrong which would result in this change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE!

Ok so I discovered now that I can "Update Frame" to fix the layout. Still not sure why the layout is getting messed up in the first place.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Have you figured out a persistent way of fixing those issues ? I'm having exactly the same problem every time I open my project. Having in mind that it contains more than 15 VCs, it's quite a hack to individually resolve all "layout issues" each time I start the project...

Comment: I haven't I'm still having the same issues. I had to do the same thing. I only have 11 VCs but its still brutal. Sometimes updating frames will actually break my layout and force me to delete some of the elements and start over. Its almost better to set it and forget it right now. Just make sure you get the layout right the first time around.

Comment: Hey, seems like it's a bug in xCode IB. Check this out : http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf  (scroll down to the section "Issues Resolved in xCode 6.3)

Comment: Awesome!!! I'm updating now. Lets see if it fixes the problem

Comment: so far so good..... we'll see over the next few hours. If it works please write-up an answer so I can mark it solved.

Comment: So, no issues after you upgraded xCode ? (i'm getting closer to my deadline, so didn't want to experiment with IDE updates :) ) I'll put an answer as soon as you signal this could be the answer.

Comment: It looks like its the answer!! Also... My Mac kept the Beta and the old version of Xcode so I could switch back, very nice of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a bug in xCode 6.1.x (prior to v6.3.xx), which was resolved in a meanwhile.

Here is the official reference : 
http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf

Definite solution of this problem :
You need to update xCode to v6.3 which successfully resolves this problem

Comment: In xcode6.3 tableview cells and tableheaderview were changed everytime when i reopen the project, and some views can't be update frame in all views menu, what the hell...

Comment: @jeffrey : I ran into similar issues even when I updated Xcode. However, layout issues seem to magically disappear in the same way as they appeared randomly while opening Xcode project .. Crazy !
What I also found out as a potential problem is if you have more than one language set embedded. InterfaceBuilder seems to get confused dealing with multiple language sets.
Lastly, during the course of my project I simply decided to ignore all layout issues and keep on. Haven't noticed any change in the actual app, even tho I have like 30+ layout warnings...